# Omnichannel - prevent work to be routed back to queue when there is only one agent online

Tags: omnichannel, queue-based-routing

We have a 30 second push timeout implemented for the omnichannel so that the work would go round robin, the problem is when there is only one agent online and the 30 second is over the work is routed back to the queue and the work won't be routed back to the online agent unless  he/she goes offline and online again

Is there any solution for this without switching to skill based routing?